# private/public key ssh-keygen -t rsa

Tags: public-key-encryption, private-key, ssh-keygen

I created a public key with the command "ssh-keygen -t rsa" without a passcode, I was going to use this for github but I sent both the public and the private key by mistake....

what are the implications exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The implications are that your private key is no longer private, so it can no longer uniquely identify you, so you can now be impersonated.

Throw it away and start again.